# ReactJS Button not routing to another part of the website

Tags: reactjs, redirect, button, href

Below I put a screenshot of some ReactJS code which are buttons that are linked to another part of my website.

I was wondering why this code was not working correctly when I click on it.

```
<Actions>
 <PrimaryButton href="/about" css="">
   Start Searching
 </PrimaryButton>
 <SecondaryButton href="/about">
   Learn More
 </SecondaryButton>
</Actions>
```

I tried the above solution and when I clicked the button, it did nothing.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to add what component library you are using, or what the sources are for components `PrimaryButton` and `SecondaryButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tag to open an another page. You can use target _blank to open in a new tab or you can use _self to open the same tab.

```
    <a className="your classname" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="/about"
    Start Searching
    />
```

Comment: Even after doing this, the button is not working.